# list the cases in text

Tags: spacing, lists, cases

I would like to list some cases which are needed to be consider in text. I didn't find a standard way to do this. There is "case" for math mode, but that is not what I want.
Look the following picture:

[image: With Space]

I use `\\ \\` ( 2 new lines ) and `\textbf` to get the above result. But I doubt the space is too large ( larger then the space before `\begin{Theorem}` ).

I also use

[image: Without Space]

but it looks like no space is not good neither. Is there a standard way to do this, otherwise, what's the best space for it?

Comment: Please compile what you have into a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: It should be a simple matter of adjusting the spacing before and after each `Case`, so solution may vary based on how you are doing.

Comment: @Peter, I mentioned that I use "2 new line" to get the above result. I thought it is really simple to "recreate" it. And this not really a problem if there is a stanard method to list the cases.

Comment: Since it is relatively simple to recreate it, you should do so and post it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I generally use an environment (for numbering) and a separate case command. That looks like this:

```
\newcounter{casenum}
\newenvironment{caseof}{\setcounter{casenum}{1}}{\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\case}[2]{\vskip.5\baselineskip\par\noindent {\bfseries Case \arabic{casenum}:} #1\\#2\addtocounter{casenum}{1}}
```

In the text I can then use:

```
\begin{caseof}
  \case{$x>0$}{In this case, $x$ is larger than $0$}
  \case{$x<0$}{In this case, $x$ is smaller than $0$}
  \case{$x=0$}{In this case, $x$ equals $0$}
\end{caseof}
```

The full example would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \newcounter{casenum}
  \newenvironment{caseof}{\setcounter{casenum}{1}}{\vskip.5\baselineskip}
  \newcommand{\case}[2]{\vskip.5\baselineskip\par\noindent {\bfseries Case \arabic{casenum}:} #1\\#2\addtocounter{casenum}{1}}
  \begin{caseof}
    \case{$x>0$}{
      In this case, $x$ is larger than $0$
    }
    \case{$x<0$}{
      In this case, $x$ is smaller than $0$
    }
    \case{$x=0$}{In this case, $x$ equals $0$}
  \end{caseof}
\end{document}
```

And the result like this:

[image: Cases]

Answer (score 9):

You can define an `enumerate`-like environment customized *via* the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\textbf{Case~5.}}
\newlist{mycases}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mycases,1]{label=\textbf{Case~\arabic*.}, 
  labelwidth=\dimexpr-\mylen-\labelsep\relax,leftmargin=0pt,align=right}

\begin{document}

\noindent There are three cases to consider:
\begin{mycases}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{mycases}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 It might be nice to setup your own list using `\newlist`, and then customize it globally in the preamble using `\setlist`; this would save you from having to specify all of the options every time.

Comment: @cmhughes You're right. Now it's done. Thanks!