# how to change font and font size when using \ref

Tags: fonts, cross-referencing, fontsize

In this topic [list the cases in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35756/list-the-cases-in-text), I got a way to list cases by using

```
\begin{enumerate}
    [label=\textbf{Case~\arabic*.},    
     labelwidth=\dimexpr-\mylen-\labelsep\relax,leftmargin=0pt,align=right]
```

here `label=\textbf{Case~\arabic*.}` makes the label of the cases being of bold font. But later, I would like to cross-reference to the cases, but with a normal font (not bold). Is there an easy way to assign the font and font size when using `\ref`? By "easy way", I mean : not using `\renewcommand` or more complicated ways. Of course, if there is no easy way, any method is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the `enumitem` package you can find on p. 3 the `ref` key, which allows you to set the references separately from the `labels`.  So in your example, if you want the reference to just be normal text, you could use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength{\mylen}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    [label=\textbf{Case~\arabic*.}, ref={Case~\arabic*},   
     labelwidth=\dimexpr-\mylen-\labelsep\relax,leftmargin=0pt,align=right]
\item Foo \label{1}
\item Bar \label{2}
\end{enumerate}
These are references: \ref{1} and \ref{2}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Note that I made your code into a minimal working example.  In future, it would be helpful for you to put similar kinds of examples in the question.

Comment: Thank you. But still one question. Because I will reference to these cases in many different places, "during a proof case by case" or "reference these cases in a text line". In the first, I would like to use bold font and in the second I would like to use a normal font. Do you have ideas to do this?

Comment: Keep the specification as I gave, and just use `\textbf{\ref{...}}` for the ones you want to be bold.