# Editing Cref for custom environments

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, environments, cleveref, cases

I recently used Roelof's answer from [list the cases in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35756/list-the-cases-in-text) and I would like to be able to use label Cref to call the different Cases.

The environment is

```
\newcounter{casenum}
\newenvironment{caseof}{\setcounter{casenum}{1}}{\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\case}[2]{\vskip.5\baselineskip\par\noindent {\bfseries Case \arabic{casenum}:} #1\\#2\addtocounter{casenum}{1}}
```

and the example edited is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \newcounter{casenum}
  \newenvironment{caseof}{\setcounter{casenum}{1}}{\vskip.5\baselineskip}
  \newcommand{\case}[2]{\vskip.5\baselineskip\par\noindent {\bfseries Case \arabic{casenum}:} #1\\#2\addtocounter{casenum}{1}}
  \begin{caseof}
    \case{$x>0$}{
      In this case, $x$ is larger than $0$ \label{c:1}
    }
    \case{$x<0$}{
      In this case, $x$ is smaller than $0$ \label{c:2}
    }
    \case{$x=0$}{In this case, $x$ equals $0$\label{c:3}}
  \end{caseof}
\end{document}
```

How can I  go about changing Cref so that I can use say

```
\Cref{c:1} is a good example for positive $x$
```

and have Latex output it as

**Case (1)** is a good example for positive x.

If I use \roman instead it should say

**Case (i)** is a good example for positive x.

etc

where, just as for normal equations, you can click on the (1)/(i) and it will direct you to that part of the document.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want bold references:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newcounter{casenum}
\newenvironment{caseof}
  {\setcounter{casenum}{0}}
  {\par\addvspace{.5\baselineskip}}

\renewcommand*{\thecasenum}{\arabic{casenum}}

\newcommand{\case}[2]{%
  \par\addvspace{.5\baselineskip}%
  \noindent \refstepcounter{casenum}\textbf{Case \thecasenum:}~#1\\*
  #2\ifhmode\unskip\fi
}

\crefname{casenum}{\protect\textbf{case}}{\protect\textbf{cases}}
\Crefname{casenum}{\protect\textbf{Case}}{\protect\textbf{Cases}}
\creflabelformat{casenum}{#2\textbf{(#1)}#3}

\begin{document}

  \begin{caseof}
    \case{$x>0$\label{c:1}}{%
      In this case, $x$ is larger than $0$.%
    }
    \case{$x<0$\label{c:2}}{%
      In this case, $x$ is smaller than $0$.%
    }
    \case{$x=0$\label{c:3}}{%
      In this case, $x$ equals $0$.%
    }
  \end{caseof}

  \Cref{c:1} is a good example for positive $x$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I used `\\*` to prevent a page break, and you might want to reimplement your `caseof` environment with `enumitem` (which would be another question).

If you don't want bold references, replace:

```latex
\crefname{casenum}{\protect\textbf{case}}{\protect\textbf{cases}}
\Crefname{casenum}{\protect\textbf{Case}}{\protect\textbf{Cases}}
\creflabelformat{casenum}{#2\textbf{(#1)}#3}
```

with:

```latex
\crefname{casenum}{case}{cases}
\creflabelformat{casenum}{#2(#1)#3}
```

[image]

For roman numbering, replace:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\thecasenum}{\arabic{casenum}}
```

with:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\thecasenum}{\roman{casenum}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! The bold/roman numerals were just examples, I am used to changing those around. The issue I have is when trying to add options to inbuilt commands. I am assuming the \Crefname and \Creflabelformat are the one I need to change for different options where the #1,#2,#3 stand for the options inside brackets \Crefname{#1}{#2}{#3} ?

Comment: I also stumbled across this <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172487/i-want-to-start-learning-how-to-use-newcommand-newenvironment-and-def-any-sug?noredirect=1&lq=1> which I think is going to answer most of those questions.

Comment: Regarding what you said, answers are in the `cleveref` manual, but in short: `#1` and `#3` in the argument  of `\creflabelformat` are start and end markers for the hyperlinks, and `#2` is the actual text. I made little changes but can't test them right now, as I am commenting using a smartphone.

Comment: Also, you could take the label from an optional argument defaulting to empty (the label would then be `#1`; add it from the `\case` macro code with `etoolbox`: `\ifstrempty{#1}{}{\label{#1}}`). This has to come after the `\refstepcounter`.

Comment: I have been reading the manual and I have managed to fine tune it perfectly. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Glad to help. In my [above comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532989/editing-cref-for-custom-environments/533001#comment1347809_533001), I mixed up the order of the parameters (start and end markers are `#2` and `#3`, text is `#1`), but I guess you got it. Just wanted to add, in case you didn't know, that since you are using `cleveref`, you can use multiple references like `\Cref{c:1,c:3}`, which would print “Cases (1) and (3)” in our example. This is a nice feature.

Comment: That's exactly why I wanted to use cleveref it makes documents neater and more organised from a tex file point of view.  I did get that mixup when I played around with the parameters. But After finding that macro page I am getting to understand the mechanisms more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `enumitem` package, as follows.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{romcases}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[romcases,1]{%
    label=\sffamily{Case (\roman*):},
    ref=\normalfont{(\roman*)},
    wide, labelindent=0pt,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt
}
\crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases}
\Crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{romcases}

  \item $x>0$\label{c:1}\\
    In this case, $x$ is larger than $0$.

  \item $x<0$\label{c:2}\\
    In this case, $x$ is smaller than $0$.

  \item $x=0$\label{c:3}\\
    In this case, $x$ equals $0$.

\end{romcases}

\Cref{c:1} is a good example for positive $x$.

\end{document}
```

[image: Cases list using enumitem]

Comment: This makes life so much simpler. Thank you for this answer as well. I really need to get used to altering macros so I am going to play around with the settings in frougons answer. This is definitely something I'll keep in mind for future and will be of use to anyone else who comes to this question.